# Display dict index or key name in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I traverse and display the dict "index name" or "key name" in Django Template? Below is the dict from the context.

Basically this is the structure of my dict `all_options[category][sub_category][name]`. "Category, sub_Category and name" are dynamic. I wanted to display "Category" first then drill down to "Sub Category" then drill further down.

Templates doesn't allow using square braces to access the dict attribute.

Thanks in advance!

**Context**

```
 'Condenser (WC)': {
    'Water Box': {
        '2MPA Condenser Water Box': {
            'option': '2MPA Condenser Water Box',
            'chillers': [{
                'chiller': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'factory': '2' ,
                'option': 'WB240.2U.F2HVKA>
            }, {
                'chiller': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'factory': '1' ,
                'option': 'WB088.2H.F2AYFA>
            }]
        },

    },
    'Anodes': {
        'Magnesium Anodes': {
            'option': 'Magnesium Anodes',
            'chillers': [{
                'chiller': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'factory': '2' ,
                'option': 'WB240.2U.F2HVKA>
            }, {
                'chiller': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'factory': '2' ,
                'option': 'WB240.2U.F2HVKA>
            }]
        }
    },
    'Stainless Steel Tube Sheet': {
        '304 SS Condenser Tube Sheets': {
            'option': '304 SS Condenser Tube Sheets',
            'chillers': [{
                'chiller': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'factory': '2' ,
                'option': 'WB240.2U.F2HVKA>
            }]
        },

    }
},
```

**Template**

In the template, I added a comment and it's the  string that needs to be printed.

```
 {% for category_name in all_options %}
    {{ category_name }} #Condenser (WC)

{% for subcat in category_name %}
    {{ subcat }} #Water Box

    {% for item in subcat %}
        {{ item }}  #2MPA Condenser Marine Water Box

         {% for chiller in item.chillers %}
            {{ chiller.option }}  #WB200.3K.F2HVKA

        {% endfor%}

    {% endfor%}

{% endfor%}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python you can iterate over a iterable if **2-tuples**, by calling the **`.items()`** function on the dictionary. In Django templates, we can do this as well:

```
{% for category_name, category in all_options.items %}
    {{ category_name }} #Condenser (WC)

{% for subcat_name, subcat in category.items %}
    {{ subcat_name }} #Water Box

    {% for item_name, item in subcat.items %}
        {{ item_name }}  #2MPA Condenser Marine Water Box

         {% for chiller in item.chillers %}
            {{ chiller.option }}  #WB200.3K.F2HVKA

        {% endfor%}

    {% endfor%}

{% endfor%}

{% endfor %}
```

(or something similar to this)

So here `category_name` is the *key* associated with the the dictionary item, and `category` is the *value* (so in this case a dictionary as well*). You can then for example enumerate again over that dictionary, and so on.

Note that in Python dictionaries are ***unordered***: so that means that iteration can happen in any order possible. In case you want a fixed order, I advice you to use a list of 2-tuples, in which case you do not have to call `.items` of course. Furthermore a dictionary can contain only *hashable* keys, and every key can occur at most *once*. This is not because of Django, it is simply how dictionaries are designed in Python.

As said before, in case you want an ordered collection of elements such that the "key" does not has to be hashable and/or occur multiple times, I would advice you to use a list of 2-tuples (something like `[(k1, v1), (k2, v2)]` with `ki` the key, and `vi` the corresponding value).

In case you are *only* interested in the values, you can use `.values`, which will produce an iterable over the *values* of the dictionary.

Comment: wow! works like charm!!!! i was already creating custom template tags.  Thank you so much!